# MySQL: Create table error with default value of enum

Tags: php, mysql, enums

When I create a table in **phpMyAdmin**, I receive this error:

> #1067 - Invalid default value for 'htmlstate'

Query to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `cms_article` (
  `contentid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pagetext` mediumtext /*!40101 COLLATE latin1_bin */ NOT NULL,
  `threadid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `blogid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `posttitle` varchar(255) /*!40101 COLLATE latin1_bin */ DEFAULT NULL,
  `postauthor` varchar(100) /*!40101 COLLATE latin1_bin */ DEFAULT NULL,
  `poststarter` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `blogpostid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `postid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_posted` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_started` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `previewtext` varchar(2048) /*!40101 COLLATE latin1_bin */ DEFAULT NULL,
  `previewimage` varchar(256) /*!40101 COLLATE latin1_bin */ DEFAULT NULL,
  `imagewidth` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageheight` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `previewvideo` mediumtext /*!40101 COLLATE latin1_bin */,
  `htmlstate` enum('off','on','on_nl2br') /*!40101 COLLATE latin1_bin */ NOT NULL DEFAULT 'off',
  PRIMARY KEY (`contentid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=503 /*!40101 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 */ /*!40101 COLLATE=latin1_bin */;
```

Comment: mysql server version ?

Comment: This works on SQL Fiddle version 5.5 . . . http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afbbd4.

Comment: This also works on mysql server version 5.6.24 and phpMyAdmin 4.4.6.1

Answer (score 1):

In earlier versions of MySQL, you can just declare it `NOT NULL`:

> If an ENUM column is declared to permit NULL, the NULL value is a
>   legal value for the column, and the default value is NULL. If an ENUM
>   column is declared NOT NULL, its default value is the first element of
>   the list of permitted values.

(From [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html).)

The first value `'off'` will be used in your case.